# Best way to invoke an anonymous function and jQuery(document).ready()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is this redundant?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($} {
    //stuff
}(jQuery));
```

This is ugly and overly verbose:

```
(function($) { $(document).ready(function() {
    //stuff
})})(jQuery);
```

What I need:

- Efficient, pretty, and semantic.
- Avoids namespace conflicts.
- Minimal.

Just about the entire script runs after the dom is ready. Nesting .ready() in an anonymous function on different lines isn't ideal, because almost the whole file would end up being double tabbed.

What's the best way?

Comment: What's your issue with double tabbed code?  I regularly use `(function($) { $(function() {}) })(jQuery)` and my editor takes care of the tabbing for me.

Comment: When all the code shares the same scope, then the extra tabs convey no meaning, so what's the point? Using Notepad++, so it's not a laziness thing, just wondering the most semantic way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery already passes a reference to itself to the ready callback](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), so just do

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    //stuff
});
// or shorter
jQuery(function ($) {
    //stuff
});
```

---

Btw, this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    //stuff
}(jQuery));
```

would even be wrong. It calls the anonymous function immediately, with `jQuery` as argument and then passes the return value to `jQuery(document).ready()`.

Comment: OK, I thought that looked redundant, wasn't sure if jQuery passed it's reference into $ like that. This is much better, thanks.

Comment: @Gabriel: It's just a parameter name, you could use any valid name other than `$` if you wanted to.

Comment: Yeah, I got you, meant ”argument", not $ specifically. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

regarding this:

```
(function($) { $(document).ready(function() {
    //stuff
})})(jQuery);
```

this is basically wrapping the `jQuery's` version of  `document-ready` function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //stuff
});
```

in an **[`IIFE`](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)**:

```
(function($) {
    // on-ready-function
}(jQuery));
```

which might be useful if you need to additionally encapsulate variables, etc.

But I usually do this:

```
$(function() {
    //stuff
});
```

and have not had any problems with this (in my 10 years career).

**One thing to note is to always put scripts at the end of the body.**

Comment: FWIW, if you put scripts at the end of the body anyway, then you don't need to put your code in the ready event handler ;)

Comment: ??? jQuery wasn't around 10 years ago so you would have had problems with that code :p

Comment: Yeah, I don't even need to worry about conflicts for this practice, I just want to get in good habit. Had to give it to Felix, because he intuited my lack of knowledge about jQuery passing it's reference, but thank you for the added insight.

Comment: You know Felix, I did have a dom readiness problem even though my code was in the footer, and .ready() fixed it. I wish I saved the code, maybe I did something wrong though. Although, portability is good anyways, in a modular way of thinking, so .ready() doesn't hurt either.

Comment: @Archer unfortunate wording, but I'm sure you get the point :-)

Comment: @GabrielHansen Yes, strangely `$(document).ready(function(){});` seems to work a bit differently than `$(function(){});` and there are cases that require the former (e.g. drupal is known to have issues with the latter).

Comment: I was just pulling your leg anyway.  Yeah, I knew what you meant :)